# Where are the drone logs stored?

Tags: go, digital-ocean, drone.io

I'm trying install and configure [drone.io](https://github.com/drone/drone)  on my server following some [tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-continuous-integration-testing-with-drone-io-on-coreos-and-docker) from digital ocean . However when I try to authorize my account (xxx.xxx.:8080/login ) I get a blank webpage which throws with  http 400 status code, The final url that I'm redirected to looks like this: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/api/auth/github.com?code=28c9ea949a200523edasdaae&state=V5dsadaKLDQC4MASSMFUH2MLF5ZVSNCWNOIDEQ7JSVR4HLAW7EMGX4NJA%3D%3D%3D%3D`.

How can I debug why this is failing? I've successfully logged into the drone but I don't know where the logs are stored. I've checked /var/log but couldn't find anything related to drone.

Digging though the [code](https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/master/server/handler/repo.go) I've found something I can't believe. Are the all errors just ignored?

Comment: I recommend using the official drone documentation. The digital ocean tutorials are not written / maintained by the drone authors, and are therefore out of date and inaccurate. For example, drone no longer uses `/api/auth/github.com` as the callback URL which is probably why the oauth flow isn't working for you. It needs to be configured to `/authorize`

Answer (score 6):

You can see the log of your container as follow:

Go to the server where drone.io is running, and view the id of the container

```
docker ps -a
```

To view the log of your container.

```
docker logs -f CONTAINER-ID
```

see the docker documentation for more info.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and in the end it was that my github app authorization url was not the same or that I was using the wrong api url. For that last error make sure you are using the one in the api docs and not the one in the tutorial (it was wrong at the time).